# Error while running the predict() function in mlr package

Tags: r, mlr

I'm trying to run a model with the `mlr` package but I'm having some problems with the `predict()` function. It gives me the following error message:

```
Error in predict(mod, task = task, subset = test) : 
Assertion on 'subset' failed: Must be of type 'integerish', not 'data.frame'
```

Please find a reproducible example below:

```
require(mlr)     # models
require(caTools) # sampling
require(Zelig)   # data

data("voteincome")
voteincome$vote <- as.factor(voteincome$vote)

set.seed(0)
sample <- sample.split(voteincome, SplitRatio = .75)
train <- subset(voteincome, sample == TRUE)
test <- subset(voteincome, sample == FALSE)

train <- na.omit(train)
test <- na.omit(test)

task <- makeClassifTask(data = train, target = "vote")
lrnr <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")
mod <- train(lrnr, task)
pred <- predict(mod, task = task, subset = test)
```

And then the error appears. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How about this: `pred <- predict(mod$learner.model, task = task, subset = test)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mlr` expects an index vector to be passed to the `subset` argument. It will then subset the data frames automatically, so you don't have to do this yourself. You can also use `mlr` to do the partitioning into train and test sets automatically with a resample description (see [the tutorial](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/resample/index.html)):

```
require(mlr)     # models
require(caTools) # sampling
require(Zelig)   # data

data("voteincome")
voteincome$vote <- as.factor(voteincome$vote)

set.seed(0)
task <- makeClassifTask(data = voteincome, target = "vote")
lrnr <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("Holdout", split = 0.75)

res <- resample(learner = lrnr, task = task, resampling = rdesc)

# get predictions on test set
getPredictionResponse(res$pred)

# compute accuracy, also see https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/performance/index.html
performance(res$pred, acc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Lars.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pred <- predict(mod$learner.model, task = task, subset = test)
```